# How to remove ReadOnly status from android emulator file system?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I`m trying to edit my android emulator (AVD) hosts file, so it can acess a virtual host i have in my Mac OS host machine.

I try following the instructions on this link: http://borkweb.com/story/setting-etchosts-on-an-android-emulator-using-a-mac

But i keep receiving "REad Only File System" messages. I`ve tried it using Android Device Monitor, from Android Studio, but it also ReadOnly.

How can I remove the ReadOnly status from my emulator file system?

Comment: If you didn't want to modify the hosts file: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: I know about the 10.0.2.2 IP adress, I was using it. But it will access my users folder: ˜/MyUserName/Sites/SomethingLikeThat. I've configured MacOS Apache to access a different folder in a different location, but that is accessed throught a different host name (Myuser.myproject.local), configured in apache configuration files. Its working, but since the emulator can only access it throught the IP it can`t access this new folder.

Comment: Use a local DNS server and use command line DNS `When starting the emulator at the command line, you can also use the -dns-server <serverList> option to manually specify the addresses of DNS servers to use, where <serverList> is a comma-separated list of server names or IP addresses. You might find this option useful if you encounter DNS resolution problems in the emulated network (for example, an "Unknown Host error" message that appears when using the web browser).`

Answer (score 0):

To update the hosts file in the emulator, save the following script in the same directory as your updated "hosts" file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# While the emulator is starting up, run this script to upload a custom hosts file
#
adb remount
while [ $? -ne 0 ]
do
 sleep 1
 echo "Retrying adb remount"
 adb remount
done
adb push hosts /etc/hosts
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 echo "Failed to push hosts file to android device"
else
 echo "Hosts file pushed successfully"
fi
############################################################################
```

Run this script when the emulator is starting up.

Verification: `adb shell cat /etc/hosts`

Please note: you can it only run once! If you re-run it more than once, you'll get a read-only filesystem error. If you have to re-run it again: restart the emulator beforehand.

Kudos to my [colleague](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/sweeden/using-custom-certificates-and-hosts-file-with-android-emulator/).