# Writing on android emulator file system

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am having some trouble interacting with the android emulator. My goal is to overwrite the hosts file on the emulated device but I am stuck.

I have used the `adb` command line tool as suggested in most places. Symptoms:

```
$ adb root
$ adb remount
> Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.
```

There is no output from the `adb root` command, and it seems to have no effect.

```
$ adb shell
emu$ su
emu> su: not found
```

I have found no way to push files to the device. Not even using the `-writable-system` when launching the emulator or restarting the adbd server... I have also tried running the script mentioned in this [other so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598209/how-to-remove-readonly-status-from-android-emulator-file-system), but with no success.

**Further information:**

- Host machine OS: Windows
- Android versions on emulator: Android 8.0 and 7.1.1
- Emulated device: Nexus 5

Answer (score 0):

I leave this here, in case anybody else encounters the same problem.

After playing around, `adb` finally works correctly with the emulator. My issue was resolved when I changed the emulated device for another model (in my case Nexus 6).